Why would apt fail to login using conf file information in auth.conf.d?
Quite a tricky problem, this one: I've set up a custom Debian repository on a remote server (let's say, example.com), which is served at https://example.com/aptrepos, and for that path I've set up apache2 Basic Auth, so it requires login/password.
Then, there are two Raspberry Pi 4 devices, at different locations (let's call them rpi1 and rpi2); I'm reasonably sure both of them have Debian (that is Raspbian, or Raspberry Pi OS) version bookworm, that is:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm

On both of them, I have created these two files:

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/example-com.list, with contents:
deb [trusted=yes] https://example.com/aptrepos bookworm main


/etc/apt/auth.conf.d/example-com.conf, with contents:
machine example.com
login userx
password uSeRx.PaSsWoRd

(userx is of course a stand-in for the respective users on the server, let's say user1 and user2, and uSeRx.PaSsWoRd a stand-in for the respective passwords)


I have ensured that the authentication login/passwords are correct, by trying to open e.g. https://example.com/aptrepos/dists/bookworm/Release in a web browser, and then copy/pasting the login/passwords from the respective example-com.conf files, in the browser "sign in" prompt Username/Password field which appears when this link is first opened in the browser - this works fine on respective RPi devices at both location.
Now here is the problem: when I did this setup on the rpi1 device, I just ran sudo apt update afterwards, and it completed without a problem - and afterwards I could immediately do sudo apt install custom_package, and it would install the corresponding package from the custom Debian repo at https://example.com/aptrepos. If I check in Apache2 access.log on the example.com server, I see entries like:
172.16.0.1 - user1 [14/Aug/2024:11:29:55 +0000] "GET /aptrepos/dists/bookworm/Release HTTP/1.1" 304 202 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (2.6.1)"

... that is, there the authenticated username is given on the log line, and server responded with HTTP status code 304 (Not Modified), which is OK.
But, when I tried to do sudo apt update on the other device (rpi2), it failed - don't have the exact error message by hand, but it was something like "Unauthorized access"; and obviously, I cannot install packages from the custom repo. When I look in apache2 access.log, I see:
173.16.1.49 - - [14/Aug/2024:09:11:09 +0000] "GET /aptrepos/dists/bookworm/Release HTTP/1.1" 401 1134 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (2.6.1)"

We can now also confirm that the user agent signature on this second RPi device is the same as on the first RPi device ("Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (2.6.1)").
So, there is no username in this log entry, and the server answered with 401 (Unauthorized) - which is the reason for sudo apt update failing on that device.
How can this be happening, when I confirmed on both devices, that the respective login/passwords entered in example-com.conf work on both devices at respective locations, when entered in a web browser?
It's as if on the second RPi device, apt didn't even bother to use the authentication credentials in /etc/apt/auth.conf.d/example-com.conf, and went on with trying to access the remote custom repository without authenticating anyway - but why would it want to do that?!?!
What can I do to start debugging, or fixing, this?

Well, I finally solved this - unfortunately not by using some smart debugging technique; but simply by having the opportunity to compare the related files on the machines I called rpi1 and rpi2 in the OP.
The problem is - I wrote the OP based on the files in rpi1, to which I had access at the time, and which, as mentioned, work. However, it turns out, that rpi2 which did not work, in fact, had the contents of /etc/apt/auth.conf.d/example-com.conf like this:
Machine example.com
login userx
password uSeRx.PaSsWoRd

... that is, the first word Machine started with a capital / majuscule / uppercase letter M - and this was the reason for the 401  Unauthorized error!
As soon as I changed the first letter of Machine to miniscule / lowercase letter m - basically getting the file contents as in OP:
machine example.com
login userx
password uSeRx.PaSsWoRd

... then things started working on rpi2, just as well as they were working on rpi1!!
Now, I have absolutely no idea how on earth would this casing of letters cause an error of 401  Unauthorized on the server; if anything, I'd expect a casing error to not even propagate the right server at all - but as confirmed by the server logs, the right server was actually contacted; except, for whatever reason, it decided that it needs to respond with 401  Unauthorized ...
Well, this is how a bad error message can end up wasting months of your time - if it just said "Error: parameter 'Machine' not understood" or something, I'd likely have solved it already when it occurred, and never would have had to post this ...
